# Will origin country of backlink affect how the page ranks in another country

Tags: seo, backlinks

My website ranks well in the US compared to other countries. Recently, a reputed website hosted and headquartered in the UK linked us from one of their articles. The link was do-follow. Will this link help rankings in the US?

Answer (score 1):

## It Should

If a search engine understands that your website would be of interest to people in both the US and the UK (and backlinks from both would suggest that it should), then a strong backlink from websites focused on either country should improve your overall SEO performance in both.